# Error reporting from a LoadableDetachableModel doesn't work

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

If an error occurs while loading a model, what is the correct way to present that to the user? It seems like adding a feedback component to the page and using error() is the correct way to do this, but when I do that, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Cannot modify component hierarchy after render phase has started (page version cant change then anymore)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.checkHierarchyChange(Component.java:3572)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.addStateChange(Component.java:3501)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.error(Component.java:1254)
    at com.prosc.wicket.LoadableDetachableModelErrorTest$1.load(LoadableDetachableModelErrorTest.java:21)
    at com.prosc.wicket.LoadableDetachableModelErrorTest$1.load(LoadableDetachableModelErrorTest.java:17)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel.getObject(LoadableDetachableModel.java:121)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.getDefaultModelObject(Component.java:1605)
```

Here is my Java code:

```
package com.prosc.wicket;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.FeedbackPanel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel;

public class LoadableDetachableModelErrorTest extends WebPage {
    public LoadableDetachableModelErrorTest() {
        add( new FeedbackPanel( "feedback" ) );
        add( new Label("dynamicText", new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String load() {
                String result = "Hello World";
                error( "Uh oh, some imaginary problem happened" );
                return result;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<html>
<body>
<div wicket:id="feedback" />
<div wicket:id="dynamicText" />
</body>
</html>
```

The expected result is to see a blank page with the error message displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what would be the 'best' way, but you can set the error on the `Session`. But you will still need to think about what you want to display in your components that use your model..

```
public class LoadableDetachableModelErrorTest extends WebPage {
    public LoadableDetachableModelErrorTest() {
        add( new FeedbackPanel( "feedback" ) );
        add( new Label("dynamicText", new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String load() {


                if (failure) {
                     Session.get().error( "Uh oh, some imaginary problem happened" );
                     return null;
                }
                else
                     return result;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

You can also throw a nice typed `Exception` and handle it in a custom `RequestCycle` (see full info here: http://wicketinaction.com/2008/09/building-a-smart-entitymodel/)

```
 public class MyRequestCycle extends WebRequestCycle
 {
  @Override
  public Page onRuntimeException(Page page, RuntimeException e)
  {
    if (e instanceof EntityNotFoundException)
    {
      return new EntityNotFoundErrorPage((EntityNotFoundException)e);
    }
    else
    {
      return super.onRuntimeException(page, e);
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Session#error() is the way. I'd +1 the answer if it wasn't using Wicket 1.4 (or older) code example. Since this is Wicket 6.x then use IRequestCycleListener#onException().

Comment: Switching from error() to Session.get().error() does indeed prevent the "Cannot modify component hierarchy" exception from being thrown, but it doesn't show up in my FeedbackPanel. How do I get the session error messages to display on the page where the model failed to load?

Comment: Any ideas on why Session,get.error() doesn't display in my feedback component?

Answer (score 0):

When Wicket starts rendering components, they are no longer allowed to change their state.

You'll have to check for errors in your component's #onConfigure().